# I need help sending embedded messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot for discord using discord.py that replies to !help with an embedded message. I've seen an answer to this question elsewhere but whenever I run this code python crashes. I've used printing and commenting to determine the problem line is the bottom, where I send the message. Any tips?

```
        if message.content == ('{}help'.format(prefix)):
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
            embed.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=True)
            print(embed)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: What do you mean python crashes? Is an error thrown?

Comment: Oh, sorry I actually figured it out a while ago and forgot to update. Apparently I was dumb and forgot to enable permissions in the channel -_-. Btw I wasn't using an ide to edit it, I was just using the official python app which doesn't throw an error it just terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Have you successfully had the bot send any other messages? When I ran your code in a test bot, it worked just fine. Perhaps your bot doesn't have message-sending privileges in the current channel?

[Example bot response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC4DZ.png)